# Access auto fill column by orher tables

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables in Ms Access database.

```
TABLES  :
     Order               Detail
       Product             Product
       Meaning             Description
```

The tables have a relation on product column.

I want if I will changing order table product column ,Meaning column fill automatically  on detail table description field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data macro on the table.

Or you can use a vba code or a macro at the event "after_update" of the column *meaning* if you use a form.

If you want to have always the same content in these two columns then you should consider deleting the detail.description column and show the product.meaning column with a query in your form instead. That is basically the idea of relational tables

Comment: I can try this but get some error, table column not found 
Database Link 2,95mb [link](http://we.tl/2O4LTYsOjs)

Comment: With this information, nobody can help you at all. Please show what method you have used and how. (piece of code, brief explanation, ...). Besides, this error message has obviously nothing to do with the question or the answer.